# Prove that $\prod_{i=1}^{n}i^{n+1-i}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(n+1-i)^i$ by induction.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, products

I'm trying to prove that $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}i^{n+1-i}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(n+1-i)^i$$ by induction. I've proved it already a different way, but I'm interested to see what a proof by induction would look like for this problem.

Comment: What other way did you solve the problem? I'm just curious. You don't have to provide a detailed answer.

Comment: The proof is essentially just a 'change of variables'. In fact you could replace $x^y$ with an arbitrary $f(x,y)$ and interpret the product as a group operation, and the same proof would hold

Comment: The question has been improved with some details for your consideration of re-opening.

Answer (score 2):

Induction goes as follows:

- For $n=2$, obviously the equality is true (the base case)
- Assume that for $n\leftarrow n$, the equality is still true (the hypothesis)
- Now we will prove for $n \leftarrow n+1$. So, we need to prove the following statement:
  $$\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} i^{n+2-i} = \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} (n+2-i)^i$$
  The product on the LHS can be written as:
  $$\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} i^{n+2-i} =\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} i \cdot \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} i^{n+1-i}=(n+1)!\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} i^{n+1-i}$$
  So now, we need to prove
  $$(n+1)!\underbrace{\prod_{i=1}^{n+1} i^{n+1-i}}_{(*)} = \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} (n+2-i)^i$$
  Applying the base case for $(*)$, the equality takes the form
  $$(n+1)!\underbrace{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(n+1-i)^i}_{(**)} = \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} (n+2-i)^i$$
  Now change the bounds of $(**)$ as follows:
  $$(n+1)!\prod_{i=2}^{n+1}(n+2-i)^{i-1} = (n+1) \prod_{i=2}^{n+1} (n+2-i)^i$$
  This comes down to the equality
  $$n! = \cfrac{\prod_{i=2}^{n+1}(n+2-i)^i}{\prod_{i=2}^{n+1}(n+2-i)^{i-1}}=\prod_{i=2}^{n+1}(n+2-i)$$
  which is obviously true.